# how does ' ' i.e single quote space single quote work in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I observed that this query returns all values from the database.

```
SELECT * FROM projround3.add_user where user_email like '%' '%';
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT *
FROM projround3.add_user
WHERE user_email like '%' '%';
```

Would not be valid in most databases.  *Some* interfaces concatenate adjacent strings, so this is interpreted as:

```
SELECT *
FROM projround3.add_user
WHERE user_email like '%%';
```

The two wildcards are the same as one.  This will match every non-NULL value.

If you want to find emails with a space, then correct logic is:

```
SELECT *
FROM projround3.add_user
WHERE user_email like '% %';
```